# How to split string with Regex.Split and keep all separators?

Tags: c#, regex, string

How to split string with Regex.Split and keep all separators?

I have a string:"substring1 delimeter1 substring2" , where delimeter+substring2 is a part of address.

Also i have 2 and more delimeters: delim1,delim2 wich are equivalent in meaning;

And i want to get string array like this:

```
arr[0]="subsctring1";
arr[1]="delim1 subsctring2";
```

or,

```
arr[1]="delim2 subsctring2;
```

I have a pattern:

```
addrArr= Regex.Split(inputText, String.Concat("(?<=",delimeter1, "|",delimeter2, ")"), RegexOptions.None);
```

But it not works well.

Can you help me to create a valid pattern to to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pattern with a lookahead only:

```
\s+(?=delim1|delim2)
```

The `\s+` will match 1 or more whitespaces (since your string contains whitespaces). In case there can be no whitespaces, use `\s*` (but then you will need to remove empty entries from the result). See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Ddelim1%7Cdelim2%29&i=substring1%20delim1%20substring2%20delim2%20substr3). If these delimiters must be whole words, use `\b` word boundaries: `\s+(?=\b(?:delim1|delim2)\b)`.

In C#:

```
addrArr = Regex.Split(inputText, string.Format(@"\s+(?={0})", string.Join("|", delimeters)));
```

If the delimiters can contain special regex metacharacters, you will need to run `Regex.Escape` on your `delimiters` list.

A [C# demo](http://ideone.com/0PrpvV):

```
var inputText = "substring1 delim1 substring2 delim2 substr3";
var  delimeters = new List<string> { "delim1", "delim2" };
var addrArr = Regex.Split(inputText, 
        string.Format(@"\s+(?={0})", string.Join("|", delimeters.Select(Regex.Escape))));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", addrArr));
```

Comment: With the `Regex.Escape`, the pattern will look like [`string.Format(@"\s+(?={0})", string.Join("|", delimeters.Select(Regex.Escape)))`](http://ideone.com/BeQlum). However, mind that in case delimiters may contain non-word chars at the start/end, you won't be able to use `\b`, some custom logic will be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a lookahead, not a lookbehind, for this to work (haven't tried it though).

Also, you have to be careful with the separators; they must be escaped to work correctly as patterns in the regex.

Try this:

```
addrArr= Regex.Split(inputText, string.Format("(?={0}|{1})", Regex.Escape(delimeter1), Regex.Escape(delimeter2)), RegexOptions.None);
```