# Split string by multiple delimiters and keep the delimiter in result

Tags: regex, vb.net, split

I want to split a string by multiple delimiters, but the delimiters are strings and I want to keep all delimiters in my result.
Lets say I have the following text:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Nam rutrum felis . Aenean elementum neque elit. Aenean elementum neque elit. Nam rutrum felis sit. Aenean elementum neque`.

The output I want is:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "Nam rutrum felis .", "Aenean elementum
>   neque elit.", "Aenean elementum neque elit."...

The delimiters are `["Lorem ", "Nam", "Aenean"]`, or maybe I will have more than those.

From where to start and what to do? I have tried something but it is not ok. I have tried split from certain index but it wont give me what I want.
I have looked at others questions but they don't give me what I want.

Comment: Post your code and let me people see what you have attempted. Then maybe they can help!

Comment: You may use [`\s*(?=delim1|delim2|delimN)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342424/how-to-split-string-with-regex-split-and-keep-all-separators) regex to split the string.

Comment: @Wheels73  well I want to know other ideas to start, or maybe using regex, I don't have much I just worked a little with index, but it is not good

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are the best, you saved me again, thanks

Comment: _"I want to know other ideas to start"_ - Unfortunately that's not how Stack Overflow works. This isn't a forum, but a Q&A (Question and Answer) site. If you want help you're gonna need to show us either the code you've tried or the research you've done while trying to solve it. We generally don't give "points in the right direction" since it doesn't make a good answer.